# continuous random variable - pth percentile

Tags: continuity, random, percentile

**Let X be a loss random variable with cdf**

$$
F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1-(θ/θ+x)^α & \textrm{for $x≥0$}\\
0 & \textrm{for $x<0$}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

**The 10th percentile is θ−k. The 90th percentile is 5θ−3k. Determine the
value of α.**

Answer: 2

I am stuck with the problem, I have no idea in what way α can be derived. 
I was trying to solve the equations F(θ−k)=0.1 and F(5θ−3k)=0.9 but I am getting nowhere with the three unknowns (θ,k,α) in those two equations. I am missing some point there.

Comment: Hint: Rearrange the two equations  ($F(\theta-k)=0.1$ and $F(5\theta-3k)$) and take the logarithm of both sides for each equation. You will find that two of the three unknowns ($k$ and $\theta$) will cancel out.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!